# Ignore the typing if enter higher number than 24 or just 0

Tags: jquery, input, numbers

I want this function to ignore the typing, if the user has entered a higher number than 24 and if the user has entered 0. As it is right now, I can enter a higher number than 24. Why?

```
$('body').on('keyup', 'input[name="textfield-number-month"]', function(e) {
    var data_val = $(this).val();

    if(parseInt(data_val) >= 25 || parseInt(data_val) == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

    } else if(parseInt(data_val) <= 24) {
        // Some code...
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/8f7th9L5/)

Comment: why don't you just put a break point there and provide some details

Comment: @Steve Break point? And what more details do you want to know?

Comment: is the function being hit? whats the value of data_val? what happen when you type in 25?

Comment: @Steve Yes. Have you seen the demo? It ignores my function and types the number I choose to type in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to remove the last char when the user enters a value outside the range

```
$(this).val(data_val.slice(0,1));
```

Here is a <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f7th9L5/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! Many, many thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. If you know how to completely ignore/block the typing if match above the number, it would be awesome! Like nothing will happen when you're typing some number over 24

Comment: Yeah , i tried, but I gave you this solution dor now and I'll try to block typing , once I'll do it, I'll post the update

Answer (score 1):

You are just stoping further typing, but you can do number 99... you have to set the value back for example:

```
    if (parseInt(data_val) >= 25 || parseInt(data_val) == 0) {
        $(this).val("25");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

    } else if (parseInt(data_val) <= 24) {
        // Some code...
    }
```

you could also set it just back:

```
        $(this).val("");
```

Comment: Many thanks! So I can't make the function just ignore the typing the user make? For instance, the user types 23 and it works but when the user types 26, nothing will happen.